# Zend Bootstrap new plugin = fatal error

Tags: zend-framework

I am stuck and looking for a solution to fix the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Plugin_AccessCheck' not found in /.../application/Bootstrap.php on line 18

I'm trying to register a new plugin. My code is:

```
protected function _initAutoLoad()
{
    $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                            'namespace' => '',
                            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH));        

    $acl = new Application_Model_LibraryAcl();
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    $frontcontroller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontcontroller->registerPlugin(new Plugin_AccessCheck($acl, $auth));

    return $modelLoader;
}
```

(This is ZF 1.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you're trying to do, you need to satisfy the following requirements (all names and paths are *case sensitive*)...

1. There is a class named `Plugin_AccessCheck` somewhere in your project
2. This class resides in a file located on the `include_path` (your apps `library` directory for example) at the relative path `Plugin/AccessCheck.php`
3. The autoloader has been informed that it should autoload classes beginning with the `Plugin` prefix. For example, in your `application.ini` config file

   ```
   autoloadernamespaces[] = "Plugin_"
   ```

There are other ways to achieve this however I'm taking the path of least resistance here.

As an aside, if this is inside a `Bootstrap` `_init*` method, don't fetch the Front Controller like that. Use this instead

```
protected function _initPlugins()
{
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $frontcontroller = $this->getResource('FrontController');

    // and the rest
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will take a look at it. for the namespacer, maybe it was better to put the hole function in my class, I did update the post.